# Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal

Tags: bash, vim

I wrote simple `jsonview` script to view json files:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmp_file=/tmp/jsonview.json
cat "${@}" | python -m json.tool > $tmp_file
[[ -f $tmp_file ]]  &&  vim $tmp_file
```

I am not using `less` because I need syntax highlighting. 
That useless use of cat `cat ${@} | ...` is so that script can be used as a filter:

```
jsonview t.json
```

and:

```
cat t.json | jsonview
```

If `jsonview` used as in second, pipe case - despite the fact that vim is invoked not on pipe but on concrete file, I am getting that warning in subject. I can view json file, but after exit, it messes up terminal. Why is this warning? Why vim thinks that it reads from a pipe?

Comment: You want to quote the expansion of `"${@}"` to make it safe for arguments with spaces. And vim isn't saying that it is *reading* from something that isn't a terminal just that standard input isn't one and it isn't it is a pipe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vim doesn't like it when standard input is redirected unless you invoke it as `vim -`. In that case it knows stdin is redirected and handles it. As a side benefit it also lets you get rid of the temp file.

```
#!/bin/bash
cat "$@" | python -m json.tool | vim +'set syntax=javascript' -R -
```

Always quote `"$@"` to ensure file names with whitespace won't mess your script up.

`-R` gets rid of the prompt to save the buffer when exiting Vim.

Comment: +1,  that almost works!   As I mentioned, I need syntax highlighting and vim here doesn't know filetype. I am looking now how to tell vim  filetype of pipe ...

Comment: There is also `view` command which works similar to `vim -R` (removed in NeoVim AFAIK).

Answer (score 3):

you can also do `vim $tmp_file </dev/tty` to tell vim input is from the terminal and not from standard input.

Comment: That's interesting, can you explain in detail? 1) Why does ```vim``` care about redirected ```stdin``` even though it got a file as argument? I never encountered a program that behaves like this. 2) Why does redirecting input from ```/dev/tty``` help? It does, I tested it, but I would expect ```vim``` to block and wait for input from the terminal.